# Does drag and drop leave the filename in an accessible place (macos)?

Tags: bash, macos, drag-and-drop

After I drag-and-drop a file, say from Finder, to say, Terminal running macos bash, is that value still accessible somewhere via a keyboard binding or an environment variable or some function or command?  I know I could kill and yank the command line after the drag-and-drop lands on the command line, but I'd like something more direct if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you drag a file from Finder to the terminal the file name along with its path is displayed on the command line. It is not stored in any variable unless you write a code or script to read the file path and name. If you hit return after the name prints on the command line you'll probably get a "Permission denied" message (unless the name is an executable) but the path and file name will then appear in the history of commands. Typing history on the command line will show you the command you attempted to run. While not stored in a variable you should have temporary access to the info thru history.

Comment: Sorry, that's a nogo -  <probably "Permission denied"> is not safe enough, plus it clutters up the history and the screen.  As I've already mentioned i could just kill the line with ^u and then yank it later (but not much later with ^y)   the filename must be somewhere, for some instant tho apparently not in cmdV or ctl-Y

Comment: that's fine, sorry I couldn't help you.

Comment: a good try.   i only gave one example.  another would be drag-and-drop into `cat > file` or  `vi file` while in insert mode